# How to find missing columns with pandas, that are present in my xlsx table?

Tags: python, excel, database, pandas, xlsx

I have a database in .xlsx format, with several columns, as you can see in the following picture :

[image: Text]

I need to work on it, so I tried to load it with pandas as follwing :

```
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
```

Then, I figured out that plenty of columns were missing, 
In fact, when I try to print the columns with df.columns (or equivalently, with df.head(0) ), I got only 10 colums when I have actually much more columns in my database.

```
Index(['Aliment ', 'Allergene ', 'Allergome code  ', 'Fonction Biologique ',
       'Mode de contamination ', 'NCBI', 'uniprot representatif ', 'Code PDB ',
       'PDB representatif ', 'Taile '])
```

How can I fix that, and retrieve my datas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you try to do `df.columns` and view the columns present in the `dataframe`?

Comment: The last part of code, starting with Index in my question is the result of df.columns, so I'm able to see the columns of the dataframe, according to pandas, but still, there are missing columns, in comparison with columns that are in the actual file.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the correct file ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try df.dtypes to see what columns you have? sometimes if you have too many columns, pandas may using ... to hide some columns

Comment: When i use df.dtypes, it shows me that some types are int64, some objects, some float64, but still, i have only 10 columns. I checked  by modifying the options, setting the max_columns display to none, i still have only 10 columns.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the presence of hidden colums in the xlsx was causing the issue.
try to unhide all the columns.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30265714)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes what could help is to use CSV instead of XLSX to remove all formatting and keep the file flat.

If this is possible in your case it's probably the safest option.

Convert the XLSX to CSV on save and then do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```